# Popup cannot close once opened multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple popup that plays a movie and have a cross to close the popup and movie.

This works fine once, however if reopened, you cannot close the popup again. We could have multiple videos on here, for some reason the cross button t close is working first, but not if the popup is reopened.

Anyone have any suggestions? It seems as though the cross function is only working once.

```js
$('.video-popup').click(function(e) {
  $('.overlay').fadeIn();
  $(this).parent('.video-img').find('.video-container, .close-video').fadeIn();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$('.close-video').click(function(f) {
  vimeoWrap = $('.video-container');
  vimeoWrap.html(vimeoWrap.html());
  $('.overlay, .video-container, .close-video').fadeOut();
  f.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.video-container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  max-width: 800px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 14, 60, 0.8);
  z-index: 9;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.close-video {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  top: -50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pdf-video-block">
  <div class="video-img">
    <img src="https://d1e4pidl3fu268.cloudfront.net/66963e4a-ccba-4fdd-ba18-d5862fb4dba7/test.png" class="video-popup">

    <div class="video-container">
      <div class="close-video">X</div>
      <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/8733915" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your intention behind this: vimeoWrap.html(vimeoWrap.html());

Comment: I simply want to stop the video when click close, but start it again when the user clicks play. Il have multiple videos on this page

Comment: Where is div ".overlay" in html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your close function like:

```
$('body').on('click', '.close-video', function(f) {
//instead of
//$('.close-video').click(function(f) {
```

Because after you change parent element (like below) you can't access this element anymore.

```
vimeoWrap = $('.video-container');
vimeoWrap.html(vimeoWrap.html());
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! Is there anychance you can stop the slight flicker when the cross is closed?

Comment: @Scott try to change `.fadeOut();` with `.hide();` (I'm not sure that I understand the question correctly)

Comment: Thanks Ahmet that was exactly it!

Answer (score 0):

It works like this for me:

```js
$('.video-popup').click(function(e) {
  $('.overlay').fadeIn();
  $('.video-container, .close-video').fadeIn();
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$('.close-video').click(function(f) {
  //vimeoWrap = $('.video-container');
  //vimeoWrap.html(vimeoWrap.html());
  $('.overlay, .video-container, .close-video').fadeOut();
  f.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.video-popup {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.video-container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  max-width: 800px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  height: 500px;
  display: none;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 14, 60, 0.8);
  z-index: 9;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.close-video {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 100px;
  left: 20px;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://d1e4pidl3fu268.cloudfront.net/66963e4a-ccba-4fdd-ba18-d5862fb4dba7/test.png" class="video-popup">
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="video-container">
<div class="close-video" style="display: block;">X</div>
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/317230912" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I comment this: //vimeoWrap = $('.video-container');
//vimeoWrap.html(vimeoWrap.html());

Answer (score 0):

Your current click-listener becomes obsolete by `vimeoWrap.html(vimeoWrap.html());`.

Just put the listener on the parent and it will work even when you reset the html (just changed the first line):

```
$('.video-container').on("click",".close-video", function(f)  {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Is there anychance you can stop the slight flicker when the cross is closed?